# How can I log SQL statements in created by my Quarkus application?

Tags: quarkus

I am using Quarkus application with the Hibernate extension and I would like Hibernate to show the generated SQL query. I am not sure how that could be accomplished.

What's the best way to accomplish that? What's the proper way to configure such a feature?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The Quarkus property that controls this behavior is `quarkus.hibernate-orm.log.sql` (which is set to `false` by default).

By simply setting `quarkus.hibernate-orm.log.sql=true` in `application.properties`, Quarkus will show and format the SQL queries that Hibernate issues to the database.
Note that the Hibernate configuration is not overridable at runtime.

For a complete set of properties that can be used to control Quarkus/Hibernate behavior, see [this](https://quarkus.io/guides/hibernate-orm-guide) guide

Comment: @ses can you please a new question for that?

Comment: ok: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59061710/way-to-log-jdbc-queries-in-quarkus

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59076369/quarkus-reactive-postgresql-client-with-jaeger-opentracing-support/59076610 + https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59072395/quarkus-log-tracing-and-equivalent-to-spring-cloud-sleuth - more answers.