# Quarkus log tracing and equivalent to Spring Cloud Sleuth

Tags: logging, quarkus, opentracing

Log tracing is extremely important matter, so I played a little bit with this code, to match/connect request ids with the response ones. This works for tracing request responses from to/from my ws.rs resources:

```
  @Provider
public class LoggingFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter, ContainerResponseFilter {

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(LoggingFilter.class);

    AtomicInteger _id = new AtomicInteger(0);
    AtomicInteger requestId = new AtomicInteger(0);

    @Context
    UriInfo info;

    @Context
    HttpServerRequest request;

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext context) {

        final String method = context.getMethod();
        final String path = info.getPath();
        final String address = request.remoteAddress().toString();
//        request.ge

        final long id = requestId.incrementAndGet();

        context.setProperty("prop", id);

        LOG.infof("Request %s %s from IP %s", method, path, address);
    }

    @Override
    public void filter(final ContainerRequestContext requestContext, final ContainerResponseContext responseContext) {

        String LOGGING_ID_PROPERTY = "prop";
        String RESPONSE_PREFIX = "responsePrefix";

        final Object requestId = requestContext.getProperty(LOGGING_ID_PROPERTY);
        final long id = requestId != null ? (Long) requestId : _id.incrementAndGet();

        final StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();

        b.append("text");

        printResponseLine(b, "Client response received", id, responseContext.getStatus());
        printPrefixedHeaders(b, id, RESPONSE_PREFIX, responseContext.getHeaders());
    }

    private void printResponseLine(StringBuilder b, String string, long id, int status) {
        LOG.info(b.toString() + id);
    }

    private void printPrefixedHeaders(StringBuilder b, long id, String string, MultivaluedMap<String, Object> headerMap) {
        LOG.info(b.toString() + id);
    }
}
```

But if I call some rest end-points (using rest clients) from my application, the trace is lost. The expectation is to see the IDs throughout the log trance from the origin to downstream to the response to the calling client. As it is done with  [spring-cloud-sleuth](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-sleuth) for example;

Is there a way to do it in Quarkus already?

Comment: If you use `quarkus-rest-client` and have `quarkus-smallrye-open-tracing` as a dependency, then any existing trace spans are propagated to the child call

Comment: it is nice.played with trace in jaeger. but to the question, how would I make it shown in the logs in the console with LOG.info though with those spans? I may want to log request/response bodies, it is not stored to jaeger seems.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the answer ist explained nicely in here: https://www.gepardec.com/jee-microservices-with-microprofile-opentracing/

```
// If span decorators are not needed or you have a custom tracing  feature
@RegisterRestClient(configKey = "externalResource")
@RegisterProviders(@RegisterProvider(ClientTracingFeature.class))
@Path("/")
public interface ExternalRestResource {
   ...
}
// If you want to use span decorators
See code snippet Register client side tracing via JAX-RS DynamicFeature
```

The tracing information is passed between services via an Http Header and the called service can extract the current active span and add its spans as child to it.

Answer (score 0):

Just to keep the format of SO, will put it in the form of the answer (I got partial answer, feel free to give the full answer!):

1.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
  <artifactId>quarkus-smallrye-opentracing</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

2.

> quarkus.jaeger.service-name=my-service
>
> quarkus.jaeger.sampler-type=const quarkus.jaeger.sampler-param=1
>
> quarkus.jaeger.reporter-log-spans=true // this will make it log to the
>   logs.

3.

Make sure you add the **@Traced** annotation over those classes/services that needed to be traced. That calls the db or http.

As result you will get something like this:

```
2019-11-28 15:52:36,726 INFO  [io.jae.int.rep.LoggingReporter] (hystrix-DefaultCommandGroup-1) Span reported: e4dc03bd6270f8fb:e62c79391515c053:e4dc03bd6270f8fb:1 - com.myconpany.myapp.infrastructure.repository.init.pg.MyStuffPgRepository.config
2019-11-28 15:52:36,726 INFO  [io.jae.int.rep.LoggingReporter] (hystrix-DefaultCommandGroup-1) Span reported: e4dc03bd6270f8fb:d512b915e876ae4c:e4dc03bd6270f8fb:1 - com.myconpany.myapp.infrastructure.repository.init.pg.MyAnotherStuffPgRepository.findAll
```

as I can see only [io.ja.in.re.LoggingReporter] category contains spans.. not any others

Still did not answer this:

Is there a way to add span by `LOG.info(...)` from the code whenever I pace it ?
I do not see any spans for that logs.
I use `org.slf4j.LoggerFactory` and tried the `org.jboss.logging.Logger`;

So basically that LoggingFilter above is still with no spans.

I would expect ContainerRequestContext to have them inside. But do not see any while debug.

Comment: plus, for the parallel calls (the one that creates in new threads), there are spans that are not related to previous parent threads, so that is not really convenient not trackable.

Answer (score -1):

You can implement this with ContainerRequestFilter,MDC and log format

```
@Provider
public class RestRequestFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    @Inject
    Tracer tracer;

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext containerRequestContext) {
        MDC.put("SPAN_ID", tracer.activeSpan().context().toString());
    }

}
```

application.properties

```
quarkus.log.console.format=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} span_id:%X{SPAN_ID}  %-5p [%c{3.}] (%t) %s%e%n
```

after this filter is executed all your logs will contain SPAN_ID

Comment: This solution does not work. Your filter is going to be executed in the loop thread while your request will be potentially executed in a separated blocking thread, therefore the MDC property setup on your filter will be lost.